MATE + pam_mount network (cifs) home profile = dconf permission denied
I use pam_mount for mount user homedir
<volume fstype="cifs"
        server="server"
        path="profiles/%(USER)"
        mountpoint="/home/mydomain/%(USER)"
        options="vers=3.0,nobrl,mfsymlinks,sec=krb5,cruid=%(USERUID),rw">
</volume>

After user login, homedir mounted is successfully, but MATE Desktop not working correctly I see logs and found it

mate-panel:178193): dconf-WARNING **: 07:59:14.125: failed to commit changes to dconf:

GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code2:
Failed to rename file
“/home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/user.LTVHR2” to
“/home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/user”: g_rename() failed:
Permission denied
(mate-panel:178193): dconf-WARNING **: 07:59:14.340: failed to commit changes to dconf:

GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code2:
Failed to rename file
“/home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/user.22TOR2” to
“/home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/user”: g_rename() failed:
Permission denied
(mate-panel:178193): dconf-WARNING **: 07:59:14.357: failed to commit changes to dconf:

GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code2:
Failed to rename file
“/home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/user.HHXMR2” to
“/home/mydomain/username1/.config/dconf/user”: g_rename() failed:
Permission denied

For some reason mate can't rename the temporary file. All permissions and ownerships is fine and correct. The user is the owner of all files.
I see https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-nfs-home.html.en and make change /etc/dconf/profile/user
user-db:user
system-db:policy
system-db:local
service-db:keyfile/user

I found similar bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cifs-utils/+bug/1764778 but have not solution

How are you trying to edit those file exactly ?
